# call a python script from the django admin panel through a Linux

Tags: python, django, linux, celery

Is it possible to call a python script from the django admin panel through a Linux script with an interval of 2 minutes without using celery and redis?
If you have the opportunity, show an example of this script, or just tell me is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **django-extensions** module's runscript component. Just set the function to call within django and call it via **cron**.

Here is the documentation and an example:

https://django-extensions.readthedocs.io/en/latest/runscript.html

Note: For beginning be careful about all externally called script files must be in a directory with a name **scripts** directory under root directory or application directories of the project.